# Query not getting executed if supplied a nested sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

For the below Query its giving the following error

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table 
without a WHERE that uses a KEY column 
To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor 
and reconnect.
```

Can anybody correct me where I have got my query wrong.

```
UPDATE delivery p  SET p.OrderID =
(
   SELECT OrderID from OrderTable o where o.DiagramID=p.DiagramID AND o.DeliveryDate=
   (
        Select min(o2.DeliveryDate) from OrderTable o2 where o2.DiagramId=o.DiagramID
   )
)
where p.OrderID=0;
```

Comment: is OrderID your key column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are working in MySQL safe mode, which disallows you to run any updates without using KEY in where clause. To disable it, use

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
```

just before running a query

Comment: Alternatively, MySQL Workbench has a setting to switch this off.